# How to convert CIFAR dataset into the same format as MNIST

Tags: python, keras, dataset

I'm trying to run a machine learning algorithm on two different datasets. However, the format for the `y` values are different between the datasets.

```py
from keras.datasets import mnist, cifar10
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
print([y_train[i] for i in range(10)])
'''
[5, 0, 4, 1, 9, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4]
'''
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
print([y_train[i] for i in range(10)])
'''
[array([6], dtype=uint8), array([9], dtype=uint8), array([9], dtype=uint8), array([4], dtype=uint8), array([1], dtype=uint8), array([1], dtype=uint8), array([2], dtype=uint8), array([7], dtype=uint8), array([8], dtype=uint8), array([3], dtype=uint8)]
'''
```

The documentation on Keras says that the format for MNIST is

> y_train, y_test: uint8 array of digit labels (integers in range 0-9)
>   with shape (num_samples,)

and that the format for CIFAR is

> y_train, y_test: uint8 array of category labels (integers in range
>   0-9) with shape (num_samples,)

To me these seem like they should be the exact same format. So, I have two questions:

1. How would I tell, from the documentation, that they actually have different formats? (If this is impossible, then just say so.)
2. How can I convert the CIFAR dataset to be in the same format as mnist? (My algorithm currently works on MNIST.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that y have slightly different shapes in both datasets, its `(60000,)` for MNIST, but `(50000, 1)` in CIFAR10. The extra dimension should not cause any problem, but in any case you can get rid of with with:

```
y = np.squeeze(y)
```

Then y's shape will be `(50000,)`.